# how to check that libsodium encryption is available in php?

Tags: php, encryption, libsodium

I have a webserver where php is running on it. I need to use NACL encryption for data encryption between client and server. However when i tried to call **`sodium_bin2hex()`** for example, the function does not exist.

is there a way to use libsodium or similar from php using include instead of installing the extension ? 
i don't have access to the webserver shell. any solution ?

thank you

Comment: Ask the host to install the extension for you?

Comment: Just out of interest, any specific reason(s) why you wouldn't use native PHP `bin2hex()`?

Comment: You appear to be missing the [sodium extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sodium.installation.php).  If you are using a shared host, you are not going to get this installed for you.  If you are spinning up your own instance, just install it yourself.  Alternatively, find a hosting provider that offers >= PHP 7.2.  Everything before 7.2 is EOL (effective December 1, 2019) so it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: i need to encrypt data from an app to the server and thus i need this encryption library. However i am using a shared host.  can i install it locally and then copy the files to the webserver?